Clickbait question and rejected edit
I have suggested an edit to the question Salviamo la lingua italiana, but apparently it has been rejected.
My motivation for wanting to change that question is that its title is not descriptive, and the quotation is not the best one to describe the issue and motivate the question. All things considered, it looks like this question is a poorly disguised advertisement for the petition rather than an honest question.
In my proposed edit, I only changed the title and the quotation.
I am not sure why the edit has been rejected and the question still stands as it is. Does anyone have arguments in its defense?

I quite agree with you: I think that the text of the question can be improved in the way you are explaining. But it can happen that, for some reason, the OP doesn't feel comfortable with the modificacions you are proposing.

I've modified the title indeed as it was really poor and non-descriptive of a very good question.

@martina Thanks; it's a step forward, but I'd still prefer something that is more descriptive and does not mention the petition at all; for instance, "termine per descrivere l'ingresso di molti vocaboli stranieri in una lingua". And I think the quotation should be changed, too. In any case, now it's too late; if the OP was advertising the petition, he has achieved his result.

Want me to change it to this suggestion of yours?

@martina As you prefer; I don't intend to force you to make that edit. My primary motivation for this Meta question was understanding why the edit had been rejected and if my view on that question was wrong or unpopular. (And, in any case, if I understand correctly I will be able to edit the question directly myself without need for review if I get 50 more reputation points...)

Done it! Don't know why it was rejected in the first place. And yes, you need some starting reputation to edit, so keep using the site :P!

@martina: http://italian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1894.

@Gio In che modo ritieni che il cambio di titolo snaturi la tua domanda, esattamente?

Non ritengo che ci sia pubblicità occulta, ma non capisco il senso di citare il nome della petizione del titolo.
La domanda riguarda una parola che indichi un certo fenomeno, indipendentemente da petizioni, iniziative o altro. Vada per citarle nel testo, ma non nel titolo, che dev'essere essenziale e chiarire immediatamente di che cosa si sta parlando. Sono favorevole a ripristinare quello inserito da Charo (“Termine per descrivere l'ingresso di molti vocaboli stranieri in una lingua”).
Diciamo così: se passando davanti a una frutteria mi viene in mente una domanda sul nome di un certo frutto, non c'è bisogno che io menzioni la frutteria nella domanda, e sicuramente non nel titolo.

English summary:
In my opinion, there is no disguised advertisement here, but on the other hand I see no need to mention in the question's title something which, after all, just spurred the question (the petition “Salviamo la lingua italiana”) but is not the actual subject of the question.

Siamo d'accordo, @Gio. Come ho scritto, trovo solo che non sia necessario menzionare la petizione nel titolo: c'è tutto il testo della domanda per argomentare e dare il contesto necessario.

Veramente il titolo ripristinato era stato inserito da @martina e non da me. Ma sono d'accordo che questo titolo era meglio del precedente perché fa un riassunto della domanda.

Potresti inserire una traduzione o perlomeno un riassunto in inglese di quello che hai scritto nella tua risposta? È quello che si dovrebbe fare nel Meta (ma lascia il testo in italiano, per carità).

@Gio: Penso che nessuno stia paragonando l'Accademia della Crusca a un fruttivendolo. Secondo me, il fatto importante qui è che un buon titolo per una domanda dovrebbe essere un riassunto della domanda e nient'altro.

@Gio: Sono desolato per essermi spiegato male, ma non paragonavo l'Accademia della Crusca a un fruttivendolo: speravo di mettere in evidenza la differenza fra l'argomento di una domanda e l'occasione che ha spinto a porla.

Due appunti aggiuntivi: 1) i fruttivendoli sono commercianti degnissimi e non mi sembra offensivo tirarli in ballo; 2) la petizione c'entra solo indirettamente con la Crusca: fu lanciata da Annamaria Testa, “esperta di comunicazione, pubblicitaria e docente universitaria” ed è solo “condivisa” dall'Accademia.

@Gio: Penso che la modificazione del titolo andasse semplicemente nella linea di quello che si è già discusso qui.

@DaG ha ragione. Sto facendo un corso d'italiano (per prima volta in vita mia) e uno dei compiti che ho dovuto svolgere era fare un riassunto di un TED (un video di YouTube che ho potuto guardare soltanto una volta) in cui Annamaria Testa parlava di questa sua petizione.

Probabilmente il problema è che abbiamo opinioni diverse su quale siano le caratteristiche del miglior testo per il titolo di una domanda: testo molto conciso, testo efficace, testo dettagliato, testo originale... Secondo me, però, il titolo si può lasciare così com'è adesso se è così importante per l'OP.
